# Insert multiple rows with SQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have an input field where the user can specify a number between 1-22. Now let's say they enter 14. Then I want to insert 14 rows. What the best way to do this? With either SQL or PHP.

```
$current_number_of_ranks = 7;
$number_of_ranks = 14;

INSERT INTO ranks (c_id, name) VALUES (67, '(new rank)')
```

EDIT: Also, lets say theres currently 7 rows with c_id 67 and they enter the number 9. I only wanna insert 2 rows.

EDIT: This is just an example. I got everything working except figuring out how to insert multiple rows. All I need help with is how to insert multiple rows.

Comment: they are gonna insert 14 rows? of what? random data?, or are you gonna ask the user what does he wants to insert?

Comment: Then you need to also SELECT prior INSERTING to know how many rows already exist for that given ID.

Comment: I have already done that. This is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You should use MySQL multiple insert:

```
$number_of_ranks = 14;

$value = implode(',', array_fill(0, $number_of_ranks, "(67, '(new rank)')"));
$query = 'INSERT INTO ranks (c_id, name) VALUES ' . $value;
// then execute the query
```

the result of `$query` will be:

```
"INSERT INTO ranks (c_id, name) VALUES (67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)'),(67, '(new rank)')"
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that you have a good reason for random inserts..

You could place the query into a loop

```
$number_of_ranks = 14;
for ($i=0; $i<$number_of_ranks; $i++) {
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO ranks (c_id, name) VALUES (67, '(new rank)')");
    //use normal db class if you have written one of course
}
```

Comment: This is not the optimal way to do it. Performing any type of query in a loop is usually frowned upon due to performance reasons.